# Redirect old domain to ROOT of new domain?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

So I have an old domain, and a new domain. Now I want to redirect the entire old domain to my new one. So I have this .htaccess;

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
Redirect 301 / http://www.newdomain.com/
```

This works for the root of olddomain when I navigate to `olddomain.com/somepage.php/` I get redirect to `NEWdomain.com/somepage.php/` and I want to send visitors always to the root of newdomain.com.

From what I understand from other questions on here it works fine for other people (it always sends root domain) what gives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a `RedirectMatch` instead

```
RedirectMatch 301 / http://www.newdomain.com/
```

This tells apache to specifically match against something (in this case, anything with a `/` in it) and to specifically redirect to a target.

Comment: No this didn't work either. It still doesn't send to the root domain.

Comment: @Linkjuice57 Something other than the redirect directive is causing it then. This by itself, in an htaccess file, does nothing except redirect to `http://www.newdomain.com/` no matter what you request.

Comment: Thanks. I tried it with another website and it worked correctly.